# Cross domain ajax request does not send response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to validate the PAN card detail. http://searchpan.in/search-pan-details-pan-no by using the ajax call i am trying to validate the pan card entered by user. I am sending pan number to this url using ajax call http://searchpan.in/pan-verify-26072017.php

```
function callbackFnc(data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
            function check() {
                $.ajax({
                    crossOrigin: true,

                    type: "Post",
                    data: {
                        pan_numbers: $("#pannumber").val()
                    },
                    url: "http://searchpan.in/pan-verify-26072017.php",
                    dataType: 'JSONP',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
                        'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                        'X-Requested-With': "XMLHttpRequest"
                    },
                    jsonpCallback: 'callbackFnc',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });


<form id=""  method="post"action="verify.php">
            Pan Number<input name="number" id="pannumber">
            <input type="button" onclick="check()"value='verify'>
        </form>
```

I have checked and all the relevant question and applied the given solution but not getting the response. Is this a correct way to do ? or please let me know how could we do,to get the response from http://searchpan.in/pan-verify-26072017.php

Comment: Have you looked at the network tab of your browser's dev tools? You should see why the request fails there

Comment: I got 200 status code it sends the data but not get response

Comment: From your description it looks like there is a bug at server-side. Try to send a similar request to a page you write and where you return a response. If you get the response, then you are either using the API unconventionally, or there is a problem on the server-side.

Comment: POST + JSONP? That's not likely

Comment: `http://searchpan.in/pan-verify-26072017.php` doesn't support JSONP anyway

Comment: How do you come to know what parameters they support?

Comment: note: datatype JSOP means your request becomes a GET - did you notice that in your **developer** console?

Comment: @vaibhavkulkarni - I have no idea about parameters ... I said that site doesn't (seem to) support JSONP - what makes you think they do? tip: add an error handler to your ajax request

Comment: try to debug the result using postman chrome tool and see what's the detail response tell.

Comment: I got blank response.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following line after `<?php`  of **pan-verify-26072017.php** 
and this should work

```
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: I cannot set this because its on another server , I dont have access of it

Comment: Okay. but I can make the request with the postman and it works fine. you can get something if you parse the request of the postman

Answer (score 0):

try this simple ajax

```
var pan_number = $("#pannumber").val();

$.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: "http://searchpan.in/pan-verify-26072017.php",
         data: {'pannumber': pan_number},
         success: function (data) {
               alert(data);
                    }
                });
```